# Required changes in kernel to use LCD pins as GPIO

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am quite new to linux kernel development.
I have AM3354 processor wega kit from Phytech.I have kernel supported by this board.
Now board have LCD connections. In my system does not need LCD. Rather i need more GPIO. Now my question is now to use these pins as GPIO. For this purpose in kernel where i need to make changes and what types of changes are required.

Comment: You'll need to read the reference material for the processor and/or existing code.  Start by figuring out if GPIO functionality is even supported on those pins.  If it is, determine how the selection is being made, for example by a pinmux or other mechanism.  Then determine if this is explicitly coded in the device specific routines, if it is in device tree, and/or if it is alterable at runtime via some configuration utility.

Comment: @ChrisStratton :I checked pins are supported as GPIO. Now i dont know where in kernel code i need to make changes to make there pin function as GPIO. Can you tell me which file does kernel refer to decide functionality of pin so that i can get any hint from there

Comment: As I said before, it could be in any of the kernel code, in the device tree (if used), or in a userspace utility.  Read the documentation, or look for board-specific files and configuration items.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconfigure dts file.

Actually what are you interested in is a pinmuxes (or pinctrl) logic. From the linux point of view the info about pin MODE is stored in dts (or dtsi) file. Let's give an [example](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/BB-BONE-BACONE-00A0.dts):

```
BONE_P8_19 (PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) /* gpmc_ad8.gpio0_22 */
```

This configures gpio0.22 or gpmc_ad8 pin as input with mode GPIO (MUX_MODE7 on am335x is always gpio).

Also the [link](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/BB-BONE-BACONE-00A0.dts) I have provided above references git repository with big amount of dts overlays for am335x beaglebone black. If you didn't catch what I have explained you could check them, so that is how you could understand the logic.

Comment: ok. I need to find right dts file for my board and make changes in that file?